# Assets2 not displaying all uploaded images

Tags: assets

I think I have a problem with the box that appears when you want to select an uploaded image.

- I have a folder with about 150 images in it.
- When I browse this folder via the Assets2 module I am able to see all of the images.
- When I try and select an image using the Assets field type in a Matrix cell the pop up box only shows a few of the images.
- I know the image is because it appears when I manually search for the file name.
- I think the problem is that the images are not refreshing when I pull the scroll bar down.
  Using Safari 5.1.7 and Chrome 24.0.1312.57

Answer (score 1):

Kenny,

It sounds like this is happening in the publish page; I reported a bug on that the other day to our team.  This should be fixed in a future release, but I do not have an update right now. I've made a note to come back to this thread and update once it is fixed.

-Lisa

Comment: Publish Page - I knew it would have a name! Thanks Lisa.